# How to turn multiple columns into factors as new columns and change labels?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to turn similarly named columns into new factor columns, named by appending "_fac". At the same time, I would like to change the factor levels.

```
df <- data.frame(var1.1 = sample(c("0", "1"), replace = TRUE, 10),
                 var1.2 = sample(c("0", "1"), replace = TRUE, 10),
                 var2.1 = sample(c("0", "1"), replace = TRUE, 10))
```

This works:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")),.funs = list(fac = factor)) 

 var1.1 var1.2 var2.1 var1.1_fac var1.2_fac
1      1      1      0          1          1
2      1      1      0          1          1
3      0      1      1          0          1
4      1      1      0          1          1
5      0      1      0          0          1
```

... but I would also like to change the labels of the new factors into "no" and "yes". I have tried the following options to no avail:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")),
                 .funs = list(fac = factor(., levels = c("0", "1"), labels = c("No", "Yes"))))
```

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")),
                 .funs = list(fac = factor(., labels = c("No", "Yes"))))
```

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")),.funs = list(fac = recode_factor(., 
                                                                             `0` = "No",
                                                                             `1` = "Yes")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `~` symbol to revise arguments of `factor()`.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")), list(fac = ~ factor(., labels = c("No", "Yes"))))

#    var1.1 var1.2 var2.1 var1.1_fac var1.2_fac
# 1       0      0      1         No         No
# 2       0      1      1         No        Yes
# 3       1      0      1        Yes         No
# 4       0      1      1         No        Yes
# 5       0      1      0         No        Yes
# 6       1      0      0        Yes         No
# 7       0      0      1         No         No
# 8       0      0      1         No         No
# 9       1      1      1        Yes        Yes
# 10      1      0      0        Yes         No
```

---

***Edit***

`list(fac = factor)` means to put each column you select to the first argument of `factor()`, but the other arguments remain default. In your case, you need revise the argument `labels`, so you need to create a custom function, then the code will be

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("var1.")), list(fac = function(x){ factor(x, labels = c("No", "Yes")) }))
```

The `~` syntax is a shortcut of the code above.

Comment: Works - can you explain roughly what the ~ does? What do you mean by revise?